# How to get a dicitionary key value from a string that contains dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a string that contains dictionary:

```
data = 'IN.Tags.Share.handleCount({"count":17737,"fCnt":"17K","fCntPlusOne":"17K","url":"www.test.com\\/"});'
```

How can i get value of an dictionary element `count`? (In my case 17737)

P.S. maybe I need to delete `IN.Tags.Share.handleCount` from string before getting a dictionary by i.e.
`k = data.replace("IN.Tags.Share.handleCount", "")` but the problem that `'()'` remains after delete?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re, ast
data = 'IN.Tags.Share.handleCount({"count":17737,"fCnt":"17K","fCntPlusOne":"17K","url":"www.test.com\/"});'
m = re.match('.*({.*})', data)
d = ast.literal_eval(m.group(1))
print d['count']
```